# AngularrJS termporarilly disabling an HREF link

Tags: angularjs

I am developing both client (Angular) and server (PHP).

I want the user to be able to download a CSV file, which the server PHP generates from data fetched from a MySql server.

I am using an `<a HREF...` link (which I use CSS to make look like a button), because that seems to be the easiest way to get the browser to open a file selection dialog for the save location.

However, I have the `.CSV` file type associated with Excel, and I am sure that many users will have too.

While the file fetching is reasonably quick, it takes a few seconds to load Excel, so it looks like nothing is happening and, no doubt, users will click repeatedly (I have even done so myself), fetching a new file each time.

What I want to do is to disable the link after it is clicked, then re-enable it when the file is downloaded - but I don't know how to detect the download (because I used `HREF` and not a `$HTTP`, where I could re-enable in `.then()`).

Any advice? I am considering just throwing up a modal "this will take a few seconds", hoping for the file to arrive before the user can close it.

Comment: Downloads are outside of the window scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this pattern successfully in the past - You use $http so you know when the download is finished, then you create an anchor tag with the href pointing to the newly downloaded file, then trigger a click event on the anchor to pass control to the browser for saving/opening etc:

```
$http.get('yourUrlPath').then(function(object) {
var anchor;
  anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
  return anchor.attr({
    href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(object.data),
    target: '_blank',
    download: "somefilename.csv"
  })[0].click();
}, function(httpError) {
  throw httpError.status + " : " + httpError.data;
});
```

Comment: Sneaky! But, it *does* look good :-) I will try it out & get back to you

Comment: After faking a click on the anchor tag which you inserted into the DOM, should you not delete it?

Comment: I don't think so. Because I am just creating a local JS variable (which happens to be a element), it should be garbage collected when the function returns. Note the element is never actually inserted into the dom, just held in memory.

Comment: Gotchya! Even if there are multiple clicks on the "real" link, it should be no problem (+1) Slick